# Como fazer um elemento ocupar toda a altura da div?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho um elemento `<aside>`, e quero que ele ocupe toda a altura da `<div>` no qual ele está inserido. Porém, não sei como definir a altura em relação a outro elemento. Como eu posso definir a altura do elemento `<aside>` em relação às propriedades do elemento pai, com CSS?

Estou usando `Materialize CSS` para fazer a estilização e ajuste de grid.

**DOM**

---

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- cabeçalho -->
  </header>

  <div class="row">
    <aside class="white black-text col s3">
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="col s9">
      <!-- demais conteúdo -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

---

```
aside{
    padding: 2em;
    width: 25em;

    /* elemento "height" ocupa apenas a área padrão do elemento, e não 100% da altura da div, como queria */
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Resultado desejado:**

[image: aside ocupando o tamanho correto]

**Resultado obtido até o momento:**

[image: aside ocupando apenas uma parcela da página]

Comment: usa bootstrap 4 olha ai q facil 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: Você também precisa pensar no seguinte: a `<div>` é um contêiner que tem o tamanho necessário para caber seu conteúdo. Então se você quer que o `<aside>` tenha o tamanho de 100% da `<div>` você já tem isso, pois a `<div>` se adapta ao tamanho do seu  `<aside>` . :D

Comment: Mas dito isso, essa parte é layout, então você provavelmente deveria usar algo como [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) ou [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu caso, parece que você não quer um elemento com altura 100% do elemento pai, mas sim 100% da altura da tela, nesse caso o melhor a ser utilizado é:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Ele funciona como uma porcentagem do View Height, logo 100vh é 100% do View Height.